# Let $a,b,c$ be the length of the side $BC,CA,AB$ respectively for $\triangle ABC$. Show that $(2b+2c-2a)^3(a+b+c)\geq18a^2bc$.

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, examples-counterexamples, geometric-inequalities

## Problem

For any $\triangle ABC$, let $a,b,c$ be the length of the side respectively. Show that $$(2b+2c-2a)^3(a+b+c)\geq18a^2bc.$$

Comment: From where does it come from?

Comment: Someone sent it to me. But according to Michael Rozenberg, this maybe was wrong. I'll ask him to affirm it.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong. Try $b=c=3$ and $a=5$.